# Vb.net DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I fill a data table with 11 columns and 1 row.

```
columns/   User        Pass 
Row /   **User2054**   1234
```

I Have a Label named lblUser and I want to put the `value = User2054` from `Table(Collumn[0], Rows[0])`

How can I fill it?

Thank's for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user name is the first column:

```
lblUser.Text = myTable.Rows(0)(0).ToString
```

Alternatively, you could use the column name:

```
lblUser.Text = myTable.Rows(0)("User").ToString
```